# Add a background image to tmenuitem from media field on page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Im trying to add a background image to my links in my menu.
My problem is I dont know how I get the filepath from the media upload field into my background-image. Everything else in my menu works.

```
lib.field_destinationmenu = HMENU
lib.field_destinationmenu {
    special = directory
    special.value = 565
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <div id="destinations">Destinationer</div><div id="destinations_places"><ul>|</ul></div>
        noBlur = 1
        NO {
            allWrap = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>

            img = COA
            img.1 {
                file.import = uploads/media
                file.import.field = media
                file.import.listNum = 0
            }

            ATagParams =
            ATagParams.append = TEXT
            ATagParams.append.value = style="background-image:url( ***** )"

        }

        CUR < .NO
        CUR = 1
        CUR {
            wrap = <li class="first current">|</li>|*|<li class="current">|</li>|*|<li class="last current">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="current"
        }
    }

    #2 < .1
    #2.wrap = <ul class="submenu">|</ul>
    #3 < .2
    #4 < .2
}
```

What should I write instead of *****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became the final result, and it works in TYPO3 4.7 and 4.5

```
1 = TMENU
1.NO {
   ATagParams.cObject = COA
   ATagParams.cObject {
     20 = IMG_RESOURCE
     20.file.import = uploads/media/
     20.file.import.field = media
     20.file.import.listNum = 0
     20.stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | style="background-image: url('|');"|
     20.stdWrap.if.isTrue.field = media
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps

```
ATagParams.append = IMG_RESOURCE
ATagParams.append {
  file.import = uploads/media
  file.import.field = media
  file.import.listNum = 0

  stdWrap.wrap = style="background-image:url(|)"
}
```

You do not need the extra COA. All you want is the image reference in the ATagParams, so put it there.

Comment: This does not works, it just adds style="background-image:url()" to the link :(

Answer (score 0):

Here comes an update for TYPO3 6.2, which is using FAL:

```
1 = TMENU
1.NO {
   ATagParams.cObject = COA
   ATagParams.cObject {
     20 = FILES
     20.references {
       fieldName = media
       listNum = 0
     }
     20.renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
     20.renderObj {
       file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
       file.treatIdAsReference = 1
       file.width = 125
     }
     20.stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | style="background-image: url('|');"|
     20.stdWrap.if.isTrue.field = media
   }
}
```